# Please explain me the below query

Tags: mysql, select

I have Mysql query to be used in a php script. I just need to know how is it processing and producing output..

```
$sql = "SELECT events_id, events_name, control_id, (TO_DAYS(events_when) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) dayto "
      ."FROM events "
      ."WHERE events_active = 1 AND events_start = 1 AND "
      ." (TO_DAYS(events_when) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) IN $noticeeventsday ";
```

Comment: You mean how to execute the query, or an explanation of what it actually does?

Comment: 1) http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
2) putting it in a PHP variable does not make this a PHP question

Comment: That bit of code by itself will not process anything. However, if you were to couple it with something like `mysqli_query()` well then it just might do something.

Comment: @Golez got me correct, I need the explanation of query...

Comment: @OM The Eternity - see Gerry's link.  Pretty straight forward SQL there.

Comment: @Gerry 1) I know I can got throught all tutorials and understand it in 2-3 hours of study 2) query uses the php variable format hence I tagged it with php also PHP developers are familiar with sql queries thats y tagged it with PHP. Spread the knowledge to the point rather than scrutinizing the questions.

Comment: @Russel I kow how to use PHP functions to execute it, i just need to know what is the meaning or how this select query will give me output. I am speaking about the functionalty

Comment: @OM The Eternity - It isn't scrutinizing the questions. Your question asks for "how is it processing and producing output". In an earlier comment you asked for "explanation of the query". And, in the previous comment you are "speaking about functionality". Please be clear about what you ask for? It would help other give good answers.

Comment: @Pavan Question was pretty clear to understand.. as One of you all have gave me the perfect desired reply... It didn't needed any further detailing...

Comment: @OM The Eternity - "also PHP developers are familiar with sql queries" if so then they will have added SQL to their interested tags. I'm "spreading knowledge" about how not to be a tag spammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the event id, event name, control id and the number of days to the event (substract from the event date the acctual date converted to number of days)

```
SELECT events_id, events_name, control_id, (TO_DAYS(events_when) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) dayto
```

From the table events

```
FROM events
```

When the event is active (events_active =1), event start is one (i don't know the semantics of the fields.. sorry) and the number of days left to the event are included in the list of valid number of days ($noticeeventsday sould be a list like (1,2,3) so if the event is in the next one, two or three days it will be returned by the query.)

```
WHERE events_active = 1 AND events_start = 1 AND (TO_DAYS(events_when) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) IN $noticeeventsday
```

HTH!

Comment: You might want to use this instead - 'WHERE events_active = 1 AND events_start = 1 AND (TO_DAYS(events_when) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) IN '.$noticeeventsday.'';

Comment: Hello @Pavanred , why you said that?

Comment: $noticeeventsday is a variable. And if its included within quotes then value of $noticeeventsday will not be used.

Comment: Thanx @SubniC for elaborative description, that is what i was looking for.. Thanx Again

Comment: @Pavanred it is PHP and double quotes, the interpeter will expand the variables http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @OM The Eternity my pleasure :)

Comment: I mistook it for single quotes. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to explain the query as it relates to you/your project/code without understanding the context, and whether you are experiencing a trouble with the SQL which you wish resolved.

1. What are you trying to do?
2. What is the underlying data structure?
3. How are your tables configured?

This considered:

1. What is the content of
   `$noticeeventsday`
2. Are you asking how to handle the
   returned results of the query? Or how the SQL actually functions/operates on your DB?